# Navbar login form in a Rails web app (with Bootstrap)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, session, railstutorial.org

I'm making a Rails web app with the limited knowledge I have - mostly from the Hartl Rails Tutorial. I'm also using Bootstrap.

I decided it would be good to have a dropdown login form in the navbar, in addition to the form at '/login'. The form *looks* nice enough, but I can't get it to work.

Here is my **current code for my working, '/login' form**:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.email_field :username, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary center-block" %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my code for the **non-working navbar form**:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: login_path, method: :post,
           html: { role: "form", id: "navbar-login" }) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group-sm">
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control',
                    name: 'username', placeholder: 'Username' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group-sm">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control',
                    id: 'password', name: 'password',
                    placeholder: 'Password' %>
    <%= link_to "Forgot password?", '#' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "center-block" %>
<% end %>
```

And here's my **sessions_controller.rb create method**:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by(username: params[:session][:username])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "That email and password combination isn't
                            correct."
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The error I get when submitting the form is as follows:

> NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
>   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

The error also points to this line of the create method:

```
user = User.find_by(username: params[:session][:username])
```

I guess the answer is pretty simple, but I can't quite figure it out. I'm sure it must be either `form_for` or the create method that isn't working.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: probably your `params[:session]` is `nil`

Comment: Thanks @usmanali, but why is it nil if I'm posting to :session?

Comment: can you check your `params` from `log`? It might give you and idea, whether the issue is same as I pointed out

Comment: @usmanali Development server says this:

Started POST "/login" for ::1 at 2015-06-05 08:23:26 +0100
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZeOrNresIkG/RrIme3z2VuvsK74+ZRi/vMoVHMQPO5+XzEVNmaGcOqmb8KVUaZWqOlhkpGPZhzbGy6plY8VOxw==", "username"=>"user", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log in"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `name` attribute from every field in the form.
Rails handles it for you and the way you are naming it is not creating the param that you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess the answer was even simpler than I realised!